# Can not send email in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, smtp, ssrs-2008

I am getting the error:

> Failure sending mail: The message could not be sent to the SMTP
>   server. The transport error code was 0x800ccc69. The server response
>   was 550 5.7.1 Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

I tried to change the SMTP settings in `rpreportserver.config` file, but didn't work.

Comment: I'd recommend visiting with your email administrator. SSRS server might not be privileged enough to send emails through your mail server. Also have the admin check if any auth settings are required to send emails

Comment: Thanks for the response Zfus. I will check with them.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same problem on SQL server 2008 R2 as following

- `rpreportserver.config` file usually located in 
  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer` and search for

  ```
  <SMTPAuthenticate>
  </SMTPAuthenticate>
  ```

  and change it to
  `<SMTPAuthenticate>2</SMTPAuthenticate>`
- Open the `Reporting Services Configuration Manager` and select Service Account then change the service account to a real account which you need to send the emails from, don't use the local system in our case.
- Restart the reporting service and try send emails.

Comment: I have to restart the reporting service to reflect the changes...anyways thanks a lot

Comment: I'm glad that you could resolve your problem also, yes you have to restart the service. already mentioned that at the end of my post ;)

if my post helped you, kindly mark it as useful ;)